# How to invoke same program with different name?

Tags: c, linux

I direct you to Kernighan & Ritchie exercise 7.1

> Write a program that converts upper case to lower case or lower case to upper case depending on the name it is invoked with,...

How can I invoke the same program with different names?

I am using Linux, so I am invoking a compiled program just by entering:

> $./a.out

What should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create a symbolic link, or just copy the executable of course:

Either

```
$ ln -s a.out A.out
```

or

```
$ cp a.out A.out
```

Then in your program's `main()`, inspect `argv[0]` to figure out how to act. This is a pretty useful technique, actually used often by production software.

Comment: Just copy the file, of course. Never thought it would just be so simple! Don't I feel stupid. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget the choice of using a *hard* link: `ln a.out A.out`. Better than either a copy or a symbolic link because it expresses you exact intention: give one file two names.

Comment: @dmckee: True, I guess. I never use hard links myself, but sure.

Answer (score 2):

You could just copy it to a different file:

```
cp a.out myprogram1
cp a.out myprogram2
```

Wallah, your program has different names.

Comment: @patrick Not sure I'm spelling it right - just took a guess and went with it ;)

Comment: Voilà is technically the correct spelling.  It is French for, basically, "There it is..."

Comment: Oh, I wasn't thinking of the voila, more of a trumpet sort of sound

Comment: @Jacob Thanks :) Learn something new every day.  I'd always thought that Voila was pronounced more like Viola and was completely different than whallah or wallah.  Guess that's what I get for reading too much ;)

Comment: Copying the files you have to maintain two versions that's why links are a much better option.